# python, string to hex array

Tags: python, arrays, hex

fast question, I want this (of course python3):

```
frame = "AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA"
```

to this:

```
frame = [0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0xA, 0xA, 0xA]
```

Comment: `0xA` is actually the number 10. That's what you get when you write that. Are you okay with it? Or are you maybe looking for the string `'0xA'`?

Comment: what do you mean by a "hex array"? That is a *list* not an array, and those are `int` objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try this:

```py
frame = "AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA"
[int(character, 16) for character in frame]
# [10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 5, ... ]
```

As @Reti43 notes in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063728/python-string-to-hex-array/65063792#comment115026206_65063728), hexadecimal values like `0xA` correspond to numbers like 10, so that's why the resulting list has integers.

If the OP desires hexadecimal, string representation can be used as below. This string can then be passed to `int` to get the corresponding integer.

```py
frame = "AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA555AAA"
[f"0x{character}" for character in frame]
# ['0xA', '0xA', '0xA', '0x5', '0x5', '0x5', '0xA', '0xA', '0xA', '0x5', ...]
```

Comment: i just realized that int array is the same as hex array, only difference is in representation :)

Comment: The '0x' prefix isn't necessary since you have to declare the base when calling `int()` anyway. `[int(c, 16) for c in frame]` will suffice.